Postgresql: Using Rank function with a date interval
I have an existing query that uses the RANK() function to sum (or count) a column and rank results over a specified date range. Up until now, I have only needed the total aggregate sum or count of the given column over the date range. Now, however, I would like to create a window within this larger date range that allows me to rank results based on their count/sum over this smaller period within the overall date range.
My existing query looks something like this. This query correctly ranks the result by total count of tracks for each unique user_resort_registration over the date range specified in the WHERE clause.
SELECT
        u.*,
        user_resort_registrations.*,
        count(tracks) as count,
        RANK () OVER (ORDER BY count(tracks) DESC) as position
      FROM users as u
      INNER JOIN user_resort_registrations ON user_resort_registrations.user_id = u.id
      INNER JOIN resort_days ON user_resort_registrations.id = resort_days.user_resort_registration_id
      INNER JOIN resorts ON user_resort_registrations.resort_id = resorts.id
      INNER JOIN tracks ON resort_days.id = tracks.resort_day_id 
WHERE resort_days.date >= '2023-03-01T07:00:00' 
AND resort_days.date <= '2023-04-01T05:59:59' 
AND resorts.identifier = 'SOME_IDENTIFIER' 
GROUP BY u.id, user_resort_registrations.id 
LIMIT(25) 

Based on other answers on SO, I have tried using the RANGE and WINDOW functionality, unfortunately to no avail. As much as possible, I need to keep the existing result structure of this query (unless what I am proposing is not possible within this structure), particularly the ORDER BY count(tracks) DESC part. What I am trying to accomplish looks something like this:
SELECT
        u.*,
        user_resort_registrations.*,
        count(tracks) as count,
        RANK () OVER (
          ORDER BY count(tracks) DESC
          RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '2 days' FOLLOWING
        ) as position
      FROM users as u
      INNER JOIN user_resort_registrations ON user_resort_registrations.user_id = u.id
      INNER JOIN resort_days ON user_resort_registrations.id = resort_days.user_resort_registration_id
      INNER JOIN resorts ON user_resort_registrations.resort_id = resorts.id
      INNER JOIN tracks ON resort_days.id = tracks.resort_day_id 
WHERE resort_days.date >= '2023-03-01T07:00:00' 
AND resort_days.date <= '2023-04-01T05:59:59' 
AND resorts.identifier = 'SOME_IDENTIFIER' 
GROUP BY u.id, user_resort_registrations.id 
LIMIT(25) 

This does not work because RANGE is interpreting CURRENT ROW as the tracks count. It is throwing an error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "2 days". I believe that this is because the RANGE is being run on count(tracks) and not the date field that I want to run it on (resort_days.date).
My goal is to be able to use RANK() to retrieve the highest occurrences of count(tracks) within a 3 day period within a larger date range (as specified by the WHERE clause). In plain english, this would be something like "find the most track records within a consecutive 3 day period over a 30 day period for each unique user_resort_registration".  I am unsure of the best way to structure the query in order to make this happen. I am using postgres version 14.12.
Here is a fiddle of my first query, which runs successfully and returns a count of the total tracks over the given time range.
Here is a fiddle of the query that I am working on that throws an error

Query Error: error: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "3 days"

MY GOAL: is to have the second query return a ranked set (the same as the first query) with a count of 22 tracks. This would be for the track ids 13-34, representing the 3 day period from '2023-03-03T10:00:00' to '2023-03-05T10:00:00' for user_resort_registration_id=1. This period represents the highest count of tracks within a 3 day period, within the larger 30 day period specified by the WHERE clause.

Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, the current results, and the expected/desirded results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.

@Belayer updated the post with a bit more info about current error and desired results.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community Clarified once again, please let me know if any uncertainty remains.

You do not use date in query. Perhaps, some kind of grouping by resort_days.date can be applied.

@ValNik I do use a date in the query: WHERE resort_days.date >= '2023-03-01T07:00:00'

If GROUP BY u.id, user_resort_registrations.id,  resort_days.date you take track count for day. Then  "find the most track records.... Now you group by whole period (WHERE ...) and do not have counts for days.

@ValNik Thanks, I know that. I am looking for a way to calculate the highest count over a 3 day period within a 30 day window, as stated above.

It's clear. Give an example of data for several days and the desired result. Such a task has a solution, but a more detailed formulation is needed. It is about the order of calculation highest count over a 3 day period within a 30 day window.

@ValNik I have updated the post with a fiddle that shows a successful query and another that shows my unsuccessful (attempted) query.

Is date's in resort_days consecutive  for  every  user_resort_registration_id? Or may be gaps in dates for user_resort_registration_id?

See example.
Step by step

CTE data - your query without grouping - source data.
CTE daydata - group by user_id,regid,resort_date - data grouped by day, not for full period.
Also we take data from previous 1 and 2 days.
CTE day3data - if current, prev1 and prev2 data are consecutive then calculate sum(trackcnt) = cum3cntL
CTE daydata_rnk - rank days by cum3cntL desc.
CTE grouped_data - group by user_id and regId, take max value cum3cntL - rn=1

with data as( -- source data
SELECT u.id user_id,u.email_address email
  ,urr.id regId,urr.resort_id
  ,resorts.identifier res_ident
  ,resort_days.id resort_day_id,resort_days.date resort_date
  ,tracks.id track_id,distance_vertical distV
FROM users as u
INNER JOIN user_resort_registrations urr ON urr.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN resort_days ON urr.id = resort_days.user_resort_registration_id
INNER JOIN resorts ON urr.resort_id = resorts.id
INNER JOIN tracks ON resort_days.id = tracks.resort_day_id 
WHERE resort_days.date >= '2023-03-01T07:00:00' 
   AND resort_days.date <= '2023-04-01T05:59:59' 
   AND resorts.identifier = 'fuzzy' 
)

,daydata as(  -- day data. Also previous 2 days data
select user_id,regId ,resort_date
  ,count(*) trackcnt
  ,lag(resort_date,1)over(partition by regId order by resort_date) prev1date
  ,lag(resort_date,2)over(partition by regId order by resort_date) prev2date
  ,lag(count(*),1)over(partition by regId order by resort_date) prev1cnt
  ,lag(count(*),2)over(partition by regId order by resort_date) prev2cnt
from data
GROUP BY user_id, regId ,resort_date
)
,day3data as(  -- check dates prev1date+2=prev1date+1=current_date
select * 
  ,case when (date_trunc('day',resort_date)-date_trunc('day',prev1date))=interval '1 day'
        and (date_trunc('day',resort_date)-date_trunc('day',prev2date))=interval '2 day'
      then prev2cnt+prev1cnt+trackcnt else 0 end cum3cntL
from daydata
)
,daydata_rnk as( -- rank for take max value row
select *
  ,row_number()over(partition by regId order by cum3cntL desc)rn
from day3data
)
,grouped_data as( -- grouping by full period and take sums and max row
select user_id,regid, sum(trackcnt) tracks_count
  ,max(case when rn=1 then cum3cntL end) max_cum3cnt
  ,max(case when rn=1 then resort_date end) max_cum3day
from daydata_rnk
group by user_id,regid
)
select * from grouped_data
order by user_id,regId;

Result



user_id
regid
tracks_count
max_cum3cnt
max_cum3day




1
1
35
22
2023-03-05 10:00:00


2
2
4
3
2023-03-03 10:00:00



For clarity, before last grouping



user_id
regid
resort_date
trackcnt
prev1date
prev2date
prev1cnt
prev2cnt
cum3cntl
rn




1
1
2023-03-01 10:00:00
6
null
null
null
null
0
5


1
1
2023-03-02 10:00:00
6
2023-03-01 10:00:00
null
6
null
0
6


1
1
2023-03-03 10:00:00
2
2023-03-02 10:00:00
2023-03-01 10:00:00
6
6
14
3


1
1
2023-03-04 10:00:00
4
2023-03-03 10:00:00
2023-03-02 10:00:00
2
6
12
4


1
1
2023-03-05 10:00:00
16
2023-03-04 10:00:00
2023-03-03 10:00:00
4
2
22
1


1
1
2023-03-06 10:00:00
1
2023-03-05 10:00:00
2023-03-04 10:00:00
16
4
21
2


2
2
2023-03-01 10:00:00
1
null
null
null
null
0
3


2
2
2023-03-02 10:00:00
1
2023-03-01 10:00:00
null
1
null
0
4


2
2
2023-03-03 10:00:00
1
2023-03-02 10:00:00
2023-03-01 10:00:00
1
1
3
1


2
2
2023-03-04 10:00:00
1
2023-03-03 10:00:00
2023-03-02 10:00:00
1
1
3
2



See demo fiddle
In demo also version for days without gap in user_resort_registrations.id dates.
For (partition by regId order by resort_date)
or (partition by user_id,regId order by resort_date) - difference may be in performance.

this works well for my needs! Thank you so much. One follow-up question... if I wanted to rank the cumulative sum over the same 3 day period for the "distance_vertical" column (instead of a count/sum on tracks), how would I change the query to handle that?

In CTE daydata add similarly to track. Sum(distance_vertical) instead of count(*) . The rest is similar

I am getting an error: column "distance_vertical" does not exist. Could you take a quick look at this fiddle and let me know what I need to change? https://dbfiddle.uk/ApgwnLPv

column distance_vertical used with name distV from CTE data.

See (https://dbfiddle.uk/X1YYM_2W)

Thanks! This appears to aggregate the distance_vertical column over the entire date range, and not the 3 day range. I would like to achieve the same "rolling sum" with distance_vertical that we achieved with tracks (essentially the max_cum3cnt but with distance_vertical instead of track_count). Is that possible?

Yes, that is possible.

Could you possibly show me how using a fiddle? I would also like to rank the results according to this distance_vertical column.
